# Brackets autofill is not working after remapping the parenthesis button

Tags: key-bindings

I have accessed keybindings.JSON to re-bind the parentheses for convenience, it worked, but the auto closing did not, when I use the old binding it closes automatically. How can I make the auto closing work for my new binding as well?